# How to make BrowerPlugin apk as preload app on Gingerbread?

Tags: android

I have a webkit plugin apk (just like the sample BrowserPlugin under development/samples). I want to integrate it into the system.img. I build it as the preload apk in /system/app/, but when the phone boot up, the apk is not installed properly.

If I install the apk in /data/app/ manually, it works well.

when the apk in /system/app/,  the .so inside the apk can not be extracted to /data/data//lib/

Anyone know how to integrate the webkit plugin as a preload apk on Gingerbread, please kindly help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

.so file should be merged to the system.img separately. If it's a browser plug-in, it should be copied to `/system/lib/plugins/<package_name>`

It looks like there's no mechanism in android to extract .so file from an apk file that contains .so files if it's integrated with the system.